# Как console.log(dir) находит элемент по id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```js
console.dir(test);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>JS Practice</title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/favicon.png?v=1"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="page">
 <header class="header">

 </header>
 <main class="main">
  <div id="test" class="element"></div>
 </main>
 <footer class="footer">

 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Я пытался вручную найти в `window` элемент, но не смог. Объясните как `console.log` его находит.

Comment: `console.log` не занимается поиском элементов, он только умеет выводить в консоль.

для поиска элемента можно использовать `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `document.querySelector`, `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если элементу назначен специальный атрибут id, то можно получить его прямо по переменной с именем из значения id.

https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Идентификаторы добавляются в глобальное пространство имен автоматически, т.е. в `window`. Если взять ваш пример, то как раз доступ осуществляется с помощью вызова `window.test`

Об этом сказано в спецификации HTML5:
[7.3.3 Named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object)

Comment: это я знаю, но где это свойство находиться?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, простите, дополнил ответ.

Comment: жаль что там не написано все же как он находит это свойство, ибо в window его просто нету.